# Getting props of a clicked element in React

Tags: reactjs

Currently learning React and need to get a prop of a clicked element. I managed to get it, but it does not feel like the "right" react way.

This is what I have (it works):

```
filterProjects = (event) => {
  const value = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("filterTarget")
  console.log(value)
}
```

Initially I tried multiple things, e.g.:
`const value = this.props.filterTarget` or `const value = event.currentTarget.this.props.filterTarget` or even using `ref` but all returned `undefined` when console logging the value.

(Using `this.props` as it's part of a class Component.)

This is what my target element looks like:

```
const categories = data.allPrismicProjectCategory.edges.map((cat, index) => {
      return (
        <a
          key={index}
          onClick={this.filterProjects}
          filterTarget={cat.node.uid}
        >
          {cat.node.data.category.text}
        </a>
      )
    })
```

Comment: @ravibagul91 Thanks for the mention, forgot to upvote that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One simple way is passing the value itself,

```
onClick={() => this.filterProjects(cat.node.uid)}
```

And the function,

```
filterProjects = (value) => {
  console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, really appreciate your quick reply. Works perfectly and feels more react than my solution. Thank you!